# Check for boolean when null

Tags: kotlin

If the field "size" is null, this will throw an exception:

```
if (p?.company?.industries?.size > 0)
   job.industryName = p?.company?.industries!![0]
```

I tried using .size!! but this generated an exception as well. How do I check if size is greater than zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(p!!.company?.industries?.size ?: 0) > 0
```

will give you 0 if `size` (or more likely, another element of the chain) is `null`, so the comparison is `0 > 0` which is false.

But as a side note: why is *everything* nullable in the first place? And why do you have such a random mix of `?.` and `!!`?

> All the field members can be nullable as this data is imported from the web and there is no guarantee that any of the fields will be present.

Even then you can at least do

```
val industries = p?.company?.industries
if (industries != null && industries.size > 0) {
    job.industryName = industries[0]
}
```

or

```
p?.company?.industries?.let { 
    if (it.size > 0) { job.industryName = it[0] }
}
```

if you don't want to make a variable for it.

Comment: I updated the post. It only uses ?. All the field members can be nullable as this data is imported from the web and there is no guarantee that any of the fields will be present.

Comment: I've added some better ways for this case.